# Import millions of lines with EF Core

Tags: ef-core-2.1

Many similar questions but cannot find the answer I want. I am trying to import millions on line and each line have information about several EF Core entities (a main one with 50 fields, and 3 related entities with a few fields) 
I have tons of duplicates which means I need to always check if the data is here before inserting or to get the FK/navigation properties.

It's quite slow. I am processing about 1000 lines per minute. I have done the few things below but is there something else obvious I can do ?

```
db.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
```

I have a cache dictionary Dictionary with a small table listing all my 50 users to avoid to query the database at each line to get the User navigation property.

Running in release executables outside of VS improved marginally the performance.

Comment: show some code - barebones POCOs (PK properties, FK/relationship properties), pseudo-code for your algorithm including calling `SaveChanges`.  What is a 'line', is it like a line from a CSV or similar file?  Show some test data as it pertains to the properties you include in your barebones POCOs.